# Safari-Like Resources (Images) View in Firefox, Chrome, IE?

Tags: browser, safari

Are there similarly simple ways of fetching images from websites in browsers other than Safari? (See the picture below.)

[image: Screenshot of Safari Web developer tools]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, you can choose the menu option *Tools* > *Page info*. In the dialog box that opens up, click on the Media tab to look at just the images within a web page.

After you open Developer Tools in Firefox and Chrome, the Network tab will list all the elements of the web page. Both browsers let you filter the list by images or by other categories through their respective tab options.

IE 11 & older versions also provide a listing of all the elements of the web page including images from Developer Tools. However, you can't filter the list to view just images. Network traffic capture should explicitly be started.

Comment: Thanks, Firefox' Page info does the job; the other ones aren't really that simple :D